# Replacing the <f:param> tag with the JSTL <c:set> tag & the javax.faces.view.facelets.TagException

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I am trying to build a problem given in a book.

The author mentions:

Sometimes, the JSTL `<c:set>` tag can solve issues that the JSF `<f:param>` tag can't. Probably, you know that we can pass parameters to the `<ui:include>` tag using the `<f:param>` tag, as shown in the following code:

```
<ui:include src="rafa.xhtml">
  <f:param name="rafa" value="Rafael Nadal Page"/>,
</ui:include>
```

Well, this approach triggers an issue! Now, the Rafael Nadal Page value will be available in the included page through EL, `#{rafa}`, but will not be available in the constructor of the managed bean of the included page!

It is time for the `<c:set>` tag to save the situation; therefore, the code will be changed to the following:

```
<ui:include src="rafa.xhtml">
  <c:set var="rafa" value="Rafael Nadal Page" scope="request"/>,
</ui:include>
```

When I use `<c:set>`, it works perfectly with its availibility as `#{rafa}`,

while in case of `<f:param>`, it gives me an exception like this:
[image]
while the author mentions that the value will be available in the included page through EL, `#{rafa}`. I am not talking about the value in the bean's `constructor`, but for the included page. What exactly does he mean?

Comment: Did it really mention `<f:param>`? It should be `<ui:param>`.

Comment: @BalusC: It's really <f:param>. You can check in Chapter 2 of his book.

Comment: Kudos for asking questions anyway when in doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just an unfortunate typo in the book. It really should have been `<ui:param>` instead of `<f:param>`.

```
<ui:include src="rafa.xhtml">
  <ui:param name="rafa" value="Rafael Nadal Page"/>,
</ui:include>
```

The `<f:param>` is intented to add HTTP request parameters to outcome of `<h:xxxLink>` and `<h:xxxButton>` components, and to parameterize the message format in `<h:outputFormat>`. The `<ui:param>` is intented to pass Facelet context parameters to `<ui:include>`, `<ui:decorate>` and `<ui:define>`.

I have notified the author about this.

#### See also:

- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense/) Mentions `<c:set>` vs `<ui:param>`